# how to solve error Handshake error in client UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL(handshake_client.cc:697)?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-http

The problem occurs only when I update the version of flutter.
The version before: 2.5.3
The current version: 2.10.3

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a relatively old question, but I've had this issue lately. In my case, it was a ***TLS version problem***.

I was trying to add SSL to my IIS server. The thing that solved it for me, was looking on Postman at the TLS version. In my case, as the IIS was a bit downgraded, it was `TLS v1.0`.

I found that TLS versions 1.0 and 1.1 were considered outdated by Microsoft and some other big companies. Once I managed to get my TLS up to `1.2`, Flutter accepted the connection immediately.

Comment: how upgrade TLS version

Comment: You can only do that if you can manage the server, that was my case. We were using an old version of IIS, we upgraded it and it was fixed.